# How to log assert messages with a custom `TraceListener`

Tags: c#, logging, trace, assert

I have implemented a custom `TraceListener` which both logs the messages sent to method `Write` and outputs them to the Win32 trace, using the Win32 API function `OutputDebugString`. Whenever my application uses `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write` or `System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write`, the messages get properly handled by the trace listener.

However, if my application runs into an assertion such as `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert` I would like to intercept what is sent to the debug output. Somehow, the trace listener does not get called with the messages produced by the assert. Is this possible? Or do I have to provide my own implementation of `Assert` in order for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you building in Release mode? Debug.Assert has the ConditionalAttribute for the DEBUG symbol defined so the calls are removed by compiler in Release mode.

Debug.Assert calls the Fail method on your trace listener. Is that implemented correctly? If you haven't overridden it, then it defaults to calling WriteLine prepended with "Fail: ".

Comment: No, I am running in a Debug environment. The assert displays an alert box and dumps its output to the attached debugger (for instance DbgView), but it does not seem to go through the trace listener.

Comment: You are right, I had to override the Fail method. Please edit your reply to reflect this, so that I can accept your answer.